# When an app on iPhone tries to log in through Google, must it be Safari? Can it be Google Chrome?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, google-chrome, google

On the iPhone, if you use an app and it tries to log in through Google, Safari will come up and show you a page to log in.  Can it be Google Chrome instead of Safari through which you log in?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no.

It is not possible to set a different default web browser on iOS. though in some applications you can specify this, that is few and far between.

So generally speaking if you need to log in to a service and it needs to open a web browser you can have it open in any browser as long as the browser is Safari.

It would be nice if that were different but the powers that be at Apple, so far, have said no to that feature.